# Loading a new View After UIAlert gets closed

Tags: objective-c

How can I make the 'OK' click in an alert direct the user to another view?

Thanks

Comment: In Xcode, you can't, unless you somehow obtain the source code of Xcode and recompile it with that part modified.

Comment: I removed the Xcode references in the question because it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `UIAlertViewDelegate` `delegate` in you viewController.h file

Dont forget to set delegate while initialising UIAlertView Object

then implement following method in your .m file, and write your redirect code in it

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  // after animation
{
    // Your redirect code goes here
}
```

Comment: I tried this for the redirect code but didn't work ... any idea why ? ViewController *sec = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: define nib name, you are passing nil, so how will it identify which nib to load

Comment: Excuse my newbie-ness , but how do I set the nib name for the main View controller (it is the view i'm trying to load).

Comment: there would be file called ViewController.xib ,write @"viewController".yes its filename you are trying to load, but without extension

Comment: Actually i don't, but the issue is that i'm using a storyboard and don't have any xib files. I tried the nib name 'ViewController' as in 'ViewController.m' .. but caused the app to crash. I didn't set up things in the app delegate and this could be causing the problem.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ok, for storyboard you need a suage i guess, look on google you will find example for storyboard navigation. good luck